# Plotting Two Factors on the same Graph

Tags: r, factors

Say I have two factors and I want to graph them on the same plot, both factors have the same levels.

```
s1 <- c(rep("male",20), rep("female", 30))
s2 <- c(rep("male",10), rep("female", 40))
s1 <- factor(s1, levels=c("male", "female"))
s2 <- factor(s2, levels=c("male", "female"))
```

I would have thought that using the table function would have produced the correct result for graphing but it pops out.

```
table(s1, s2)
        s2 
s1       male female   
male     10     10   
female    0     30
```

So really two questions, what is the table function doing to get this result and what other function can i use to create a graph with 2 series using functions with the same levels?

Also if it is a factor I'm using barplot2 in the gplots package to graph it.

Comment: Your 3rd line should be s1 <- factor(s1, levels = c("male", "female")). Also, what type of plot are you expecting? If you plot(table(s1, s2)) you will get a mosiac plot of the contingency table.

Comment: Ah sorry, i was careless when i was typing out the sample data into here. I was hoping to have a barplot with each s1 and s2 mapped on the same graph showing the number of occurrences between male and female.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve slightly more detailed results with lattice package:

```
s1 <- factor(c(rep("male",20), rep("female", 30)))
s2 <- factor(c(rep("male",10), rep("female", 40)))
D <- data.frame(s1, s2)

library(lattice)
histogram(~s1+s2, D, col = c("pink", "lightblue"))
```

[image]

Or if you want males/females side by side for easier comparison:

```
t1 <- table(s1)
t2 <- table(s2)
barchart(cbind(t1, t2), stack = F, horizontal = F)
```

[image]

Comment: You should really specify the order of the factors in the `factor` call. It would be nicer to have the boys in blue and the girls in pink ;) (+1 anyway!)

Comment: @nico Good sense of color :). Corrected.

Comment: I like lattice as Homer S. likes beer. So I'm giving you a +1. :)

Answer (score 3):

From `?table`:

> ‘table’ uses the cross-classifying factors to build a contingency
>     table of the counts at each combination of factor levels.

When you do `table(s1,s2)` what happens is that the function considers `s1` and `s2` as paired results. Effectively it tells you that if you were to take `cbind(s1,s2)` then there would be 10 rows of male-male, 10 of male-female and so on.

To understand this consider a very trivial example:

```
a <- c("M","M","F","F")
b <- c("F","F","M","M")
table(a,b)

  b
a   F M
  F 0 2
  M 2 0
```

What you should do is:

```
t1 <- table(s1)
t2 <- table(s2)
barplot(cbind(t1,t2), beside=TRUE, col=c("lightblue", "salmon"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Two options producing slightly different forms of plots are

```
plot(s1, s2)
```

and

```
plot(table(s1,s2))
```

The former is a spineplot a special case of the mosaic plot, which the `plot` method for `table` produces (the second example). See `?spineplot` and `?mosaicplot` for more details and you can use these functions directly, rather than the generic `plot()` if you wish.

Also take a look at the `mosaic()` function in the `vcd` package on CRAN by Meyer et al [(Link to vcd on CRAN)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/index.html)

`table()` is producing the [contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) for the two factors.

Comment: That is not what he is looking for. He simply needs to call `table` twice.

Comment: @nico - both the plots draw both factors on the same plot. These views of the data provide alternative (arguably better) descriptions of the type of data Cam B showed. I didn't notice that in his *comment* he asked specifically for a barplot.

Comment: @nico - I was specifically answering this part of Cam's Q: "what other function can i use to create a graph with 2 series using functions with the same levels?"

Comment: @ucagls: Ok, now that I re-read the question I am not really sure... maybe he should clarify. I thought he wanted the TOTAL number of males and females in the two groups... otherwise why would he be complaining about the `table` output?

Comment: @nico: Yeah, the Q isn't very clear. I interpreted it not as a complaint about `table` but how to plot it? With our two answers, hopefully we cover both possibilities and Cam will be a happy bunny ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I don't think creating a contingency table is what Cameron was looking for. If I understood him correctly, I think he wanted to create a data frame with two variables in it, where s1 and s2 seems to be vectors of the same size. (length(s1)==length(s2)).

In this case, he would simply need to create a "table" (I think he meant data.frame) using:

```
df = data.frame(s1=s1, s2=s2);
```

And then plot the 2 series in the same plot.

So as for the second question of plotting these things, I'd use matplot. For example:

```
matplot(1:10, data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b=rnorm(10)), type="l", lty=1, lwd=1, col=c("blue","red"))
```

Given that he has his data of 2 vectors organized in a single data.frame named "df", he can just do something like:

```
matplot(df, type="l", lty=1, lwd=1, col=c("blue","red"))
```

Hope this helps.